# NameServer SOA records misconfigured

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, nameserver

This is my config of NS.

```
hostingdk.com. SOA zone1.hostingdk.com admin.hostingdk.com
2010051905;
43100;
7200;
2419100;
86400;

hostingdk.com. NS zone1.hostingdk.com.
hostingdk.com. NS zone2.hostingdk.com.

zone1.hostingdk.com. A 96.30.49.11
zone2.hostingdk.com. A 96.30.46.238
```

Both zone1 & zone2 have registered name server in Enom domain control panel.

My problem is, one domain .lv cant not change DNS to my NS. They said:

```
Error : Nameserver zone1.hostingdk.com cannot be queried for SOA
Error : Nameserver zone2.hostingdk.com cannot be queried for SOA
```

Please help me, how to fix it ?

Comment: What is the domain you are trying to point to the DNS? If you can provide us with that detail, we can probably diagnose the issue easier.

Comment: he already did - it's in the SOA record above

Answer (score 3):

The error being reported is because your two servers (`zone1` and `zone2` above) are not correctly serving your zone file:

```
% dig +norec @96.30.46.238 hostingdk.com. soa

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> +norec @96.30.46.238 hostingdk.com. soa
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 5139
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

This may be because of the semi-colon issue pointed out by @Dom - in which case the server logs on those two boxes should tell you that.  If you're running BIND, use `named-checkzone` to check the syntax of your zone files.

If you've actually got the right syntax now, but it's still not working, you need to look at the ACLs in your server - make sure that you're actually permitting access to that zone from `0.0.0.0/0` (aka "any").

Answer (score 0):

If your are in bind format, the SOA must not have semicolon between the fields.
In my case, it is :

```
 @       SOA     dns1.grenoble.cnrs.fr. dnsmaster.grenoble.cnrs.fr. ( 2010051802 3600 900 604800 3600 )
```